# generate time series for day & year fluctuations using python

Tags: python, numpy, math, time-series, trigonometry

I want to generate a time series with temperature as the y axis and hours in a year as the x axis.
I am thinking of two sine waves:
1 - One with the period set to 1 day (to simulate low temp at night and high temp during the day).
The amplitude can also be simple, i.e. 1, and with vertical_shift = 25.
2 - the first wave is "embedded" inside a bigger, seasonal wave.

What is the correct way to simulate this using python?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation is enclosed. It makes use of the fact that cos(2*pi*t/T) will have a period of T. Taking T=24 and T=24*365 creates cosine waves that vary over a day and year, respectively. The minus signs resemble the situation with observations starting in the middle of winter and the middle of the night.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# parameters
MeanTemp = 15           # Average temperature in the country
DailyAmpl = 10          # Amplitude of the daily cycle
YearlyAmpl = 1          # Amplitude of the yearly cycle
NoiseStd = 0.1          # Standard deviation of normally distributed error term

# Total hours in year
TotalHours = 24*365

# Generate the frequency components of the data
x = np.arange(0, TotalHours)
DailyCycle = -DailyAmpl*np.cos( (2*np.pi)*x/24 )
YearlyCycle = -YearlyAmpl*np.cos( (2*np.pi)*x/TotalHours )
Noise = np.random.normal(0, NoiseStd, TotalHours)

# Final series
y = MeanTemp + DailyCycle + YearlyCycle + Noise

# Visualise result
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
axs[0].plot(y)
axs[0].set_title('Complete series')
axs[1].plot(y[0:(10*24)])
axs[1].set_title('First ten days')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That works, thanks @Hanno.
How to make the datapoints be in other frequency (i.e. not one datapoint every 1hour, but lets say every 1 minute or 1 second.
I tried to update x by:

 `seconds_per_day = 24*60*60`
 `rate_datapoints = 1  # every second`
```datapoints_per_day = seconds_per_day / rate_datapoints
x = np.arrange(0,TotalHours * datapoints_per_day) ```
(for simplicity I removed noise for now).
But the y plot does not look correct (too cluttered)

Comment: To get 1 observation per minute, you can define TotalMin = 24*365*60 and update the periods of the cos accordingly (24*60 for the daily cycle and TotalMin for the yearly cycle). However, do note that more points will make the plot even more cluttered...